# SetCheck in ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI function not working correctly

Tags: mfc

In this function `pCmdUI->SetText` works, but `pCmdUI->SetCheck` does not work correctly.

I have a menu item, I want to click it and show a check hook in the menu item, but I add a message method `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`, in this function I can use `pCmdUI->SetText("xxx")` and the menu item text changes as expected, but if I use `pCmdUI->SetCheck(TRUE)` or `pCmdUI->SetRadio(TRUE)`, it just shows me a square box instead of the "check hook".

What is happening here?

This is my code:

```
void CBaoSteelBaseView::OnUpdateTrueImage(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
  pCmdUI->Enable(pImage!=NULL && !pImage->IsEmpty());
  if (systemInfo.showTrueImage)
  {
     pCmdUI->SetCheck(TRUE);
  }
  else if (!systemInfo.showTrueImage)
  {
    pCmdUI->SetCheck(FALSE); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You need to elaborate your question. As it stands here nobody understands what you actually want.

Comment: Yes, its' more clear now, but please don't put clarifications into a comment but [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45227498/edit) and put that information __there__.

Comment: Maybe it's because you have a chinese Windows. Can you check if it works correctly on an English Windows? Which Visual Studio are you busing, which Windoes do you have (7,8,10, XP,...)?

Comment: but in other menu item ,i can use this way `pCmdUI->SetCheck(True)` to implement this 'check the hook' , but this is not work.

Comment: Not quite clear. Are you saying that `pCmdUI->SetCheck(TRUE)` works correctly in one menu but not in another one?

Comment: yes,in other menu item ,i can use this way pCmdUI->SetCheck(True) to implement this 'check the hook',but this is not work

Comment: the difference of between this menu item and other menu item, i implement it which can not work in view class,and i implement other which can work in MainFrame. but i try use same way implement it which can not work in MainFrame,it still can not work, just show me a square box but not have check box hook

Comment: OK now your problem description is complete. Unfortunately I don't have a solution ready. I agree that this behaviour is rather strange. BTW the answer below is not supposed to resolve your problem, it's just a side note.

Comment: but still thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but just a side note:

Your code is overly complicated. You can replace it by this:

```
void CBaoSteelBaseView::OnUpdateTrueImage(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
  pCmdUI->Enable(pImage!=NULL && !pImage->IsEmpty());
  if (systemInfo.showTrueImage)
  {
     pCmdUI->SetCheck(TRUE);
  }
  else
  {
    pCmdUI->SetCheck(FALSE); 
  } 
}
```

or even simpler:

```
void CBaoSteelBaseView::OnUpdateTrueImage(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
  pCmdUI->Enable(pImage!=NULL && !pImage->IsEmpty());
  pCmdUI->SetCheck(systemInfo.showTrueImage); 
}
```

Comment: `SetCheck` does not take a `BOOL` argument, but an `int`. 0 = unchecked, 1 = checked, 2 = indeterminate.

Comment: @MariusBancila that's correct, but it actually doesn't change anything because `TRUE` is defined as `1`.